# Can someone explain to me what is going on within this nested loop?

Tags: java

Someone please explain what is going on within the nested loop below. I'm having trouble understanding how it works.

```
int numberOfTimesheets;
int centsPerHour = 0;
int hoursWorked;
total = 0;
numberOfTimesheets = stdin.nextInt();

for(int i = 1; i <= numberOfTimesheets; i++){
   hoursWorked = 0;
   centsPerHour = stdin.nextInt();
   for (int ii = 1; ii <= 5; ii++){
      hoursWorked = hoursWorked + stdin.nextInt();
   }
   total = total + (hoursWorked * centsPerHour);
}
```

Comment: What exactly about it don't you understand? The names of the variables should be a huge clue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the code commented with what it is doing at each step:

```
//go through each time sheet
for(int i = 1; i <= numberOfTimesheets; i++){
    hoursWorked = 0; // reset the number of hours worked (presumably for that week).
    centsPerHour = stdin.nextInt(); //get the wage of the current timesheet

    //go through each day for the current timesheet
    for (int ii = 1; ii <= 5; ii++){
        hoursWorked = hoursWorked + stdin.nextInt(); //add up the number of hours worked in that week
    }
    total = total + (hoursWorked * centsPerHour); //add the amount of money made this week to their current total (salary).
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Nested `for` loop is itearting 5 times, summing 5 user inputs to variable `hoursWorked`. Point to all this is probably to count number of hours the user worked in that week (each iteration for each day of the week). Then get his salary by multiplying his hours by his pay per hour, and add it to `total`.

It's pretty straightforward, the only thing you may not understand is:

`hoursWorked = hoursWorked + stdin.nextInt();`

It translates to something like this:

`new value of hoursWorked = old value of hoursWorked + userInput`

It can also be written as:

`hoursWorked += stdin.nextInt();`

Comment: What exactly is affecting the old number of hoursWorked? The numberOfTimesheets? From what I see, the first loop is gathering the pay information and the second loop runs the calculation?